# Codeigniter does not work without index.php in Get requests?

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I use the following .htaccess:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
DirectoryIndex index.php
Options All -Indexes

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Also settings in Codeigniter:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

So, all pages are opened by the URL path `domain/index.php/page`

But it does not work for `domain/page`

Comment: Seems does not work htaccess, how can I check this? Because mod_rewrite is on

Comment: What version of codeigniter you using?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
> ```

Try changing the above line to the following:

```
RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1 [L]
```

Specifically, the `?` in the substitution is removed. So, rather than passing the requested URL as part of the query string (which would prevent any additional query string being used), it is passed as additional PATH INFO instead.

The anchors around the `RewriteRule` pattern are also not required. And the slash prefix on the substitution can be removed also - this is what the `RewriteBase` directive is for.

> ```
> Options All -Indexes
> ```

Also, this is not strictly valid. You should not mix +/- params with those without. This should probably just be:

```
Options -Indexes
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

In Config file

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

Comment: Let me know if you have any query !